# Clear default search text on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have the following code to put helper text in a search input box that is removed when you click in the box and returned if you click anywhere else without changing it:

```
$('#search-form input[type="text"]').each(function(){
    var defaultVal = 'Category Search';
    $(this).focus(function(){
      if ($(this).val() == defaultVal){
        $(this).removeClass('active').val('').css('color', '#000');;
      }
    })
    .blur(function(){
      if ($(this).val() == ''){
        $(this).addClass('active').val(defaultVal).css('color', '#CCC');
      }
    })
    .blur().addClass('active');
});
```

But if the user clicks submit without clicking in the input box, the site will search for the helper value (Category Search).

What I need to do is on submit check the value and if it's `Category Search` then do the following things:

- Change helper text to `Please enter a category`
- Don't submit the form.

I tried this but it stopped my default value (Category Search) from working all together:

```
$('#search-form input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "Category Search")
        //do stuff here
});​
```

Comment: Can't you just use the `placeholder` attribute and a [polyfill](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js) to add support in older browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ewowoq/3/edit)*

```
var defaultVal = 'Category Search';
var enterCat = 'Please enter a category';

$('#search-form input[type="text"]').each(function(){
  
    $(this).focus(function(){
      if ($(this).val() == defaultVal || $(this).val() == enterCat){
        $(this).removeClass('active').val('').css('color', '#000');
      }
    })
    .blur(function(){
      if ($.trim($(this).val()) === ''){
        $(this).addClass('active').val(defaultVal).css('color', '#CCC');
      }
    })
    .blur().addClass('active');
});

$('#search-form').submit(function(e) {
  
  if ( $(this).find('[type="text"]').val() === defaultVal){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('[type="text"]').prop('value', enterCat);    
  } 
  
});
```

and use also `$.trim()` (whitespaces) before searching for blank inputs :)

Answer (score 2):

[HTML5 placeholder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input#attr-placeholder) is what you should use for browsers that support it, there would be no code to write to remove it.

For browsers that do not support it, there are plenty of plugins that make it work.

And why do you not just ignore the default value on the server? Seems like a logical place to filter it out.

The reason why your code fails is this is the submit button, not the form fields!

```
$('#search-form input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
if ($(this).val() == "Category Search")  <-- this is the submit button, not the input
    //do stuff here
});​
```

You need to change it to point to the inputs

```
$('#search-form').on("submit",function() {
    $('#search-form input[type="text"]').each( function() {
        //do comparison here, you could use defaultValue attribute
    } );
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use the `placeholder` (and you really should if you can), then you could simply set the field to `disabled`:

```
$('#search-form input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "Category Search") {
        $(this).prop('disabled',true);
    }
});​
```

The `disabled` attribute essentially guarantees that the field is 'not successful', and thus won't be submitted to the server.

> A successful control is "valid" for submission. Every successful control has its control name paired with its current value as part of the submitted form data set. A successful control must be defined within a FORM element and must have a control name.
>
> However:
>
> - Controls that are disabled cannot be successful...

[Citation: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2).

Answer (score 1):

I agree on using `placeholder`, but this is the answer to your question:

```
$('#search-form input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
if ($('#search-form input[type="text"]') == "Category Search")
    $('#search-form input[type="text"]').val("Please enter a category");
    return false;
});​
```

I, personally, would create an error box near to the search field rather than change the text already in it - otherwise you're going to have problems with people submitting 'please enter a category'...

Comment: +1 but e.preventDefault() should be better here and dont forget: if ($(this).val() === "Category Search" || $(this).val() === "Please enter a category")

Comment: Agree on preventDefault() being better. As noted, I'd leave the text box alone and put the message somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get the .val() of the submit button

```
$('#search-form input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
   if ($('#search-form input[type="text"]').val() == "Category Search")
      //do stuff here
});​
```

but you should probably hook it to submit event of the form itself, but that would depend on how your implementation actually works.

```
 $('#search-form').submit(function() {
   if ($('#search-form input[type="text"]').val() == "Category Search")
      //do stuff here
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler: Most new browsers will allow this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="your prompt here" />
```

But for older browsers you can do this:

```
$(function() {
  if ($.browser.msie) {
    $('#search-form input[type="text"]').each(function(){       
      $(this).val($(this).attr("placeholder"));
    });
  }
  $("#search-form").on("submit",function() {
    var cnt=0,empty++;
    $("#search-form input[type='text']").each(function(){
      var box = $(this),val = box.val();
      if (val == box.attr("placeholder")){
        box.val("");
      }
      else {
        box.val($.trim(val));
      }
      if (box.val()=="") empty++;
      cnt++;
    });
    if (empty==cnt) return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: That still submits the form, though.